# Can't Identify Source of Vertical Line on Website

Tags: html, css

I'm using JS Bin to develop some advanced JavaScript. My current project can be seen at http://jsbin.com/uciviy/20.

However, at the moment this page shows a vertical gray line. (It is visible just to the right of the Sales Costing header, and it continues to the bottom of the page.)

I don't seem able to identify what is causing this. Either way, I don't want it. Can anyone see where it's coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML body appears to have a CSS style that is adding a background image in master.css with a source of '../images/leftmenu_background.gif' which I believe is creating your vertical line.

Here's the offending image: https://ovation.viperdmc.com/images/leftmenu_background.gif

Comment: Yep, that appears to be it. That's odd. (I didn't write the original HTML.) Thanks! (And nice photo.)

Comment: Thanks! Those weird artifacts are always fun to hunt down :)

Comment: Nicely found; I was looking for some form of floated/empty element introduced by the JavaScript. +1 =)

Comment: Man, I've had some similar background image surprises. Chrome inspector FTW <3

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code at master.css on line 1

```
    background-image: url(../images/leftmenu_background.gif);
```